# dependent Lov in oracle forms 10g

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I have database block table columns , that has no values means not inserted any values , i have 2 columns in that block order_no,order_name , table name called xx_customer_details, so i need to create LOV on order_no column using oracle table customer_details ,my requirement is i am selecting Order_no vlaues from LOV then need to populate in the order_name column automatically

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this, you simply create a RECORD GROUP with the required columns

```
select order_no,order_name from xx_customer_details;
```

Now create LOV and assign this record group to it.
In your LOV properties you find Column Mapping properties and map the columns accordingly.
And finally assign this LOV to your text item.
Then you are done.